# Network Adapter Unrecognized on Boot

Tags: networking, usb

Hello I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on a fairly clean install. This problem I will explain **only happens on Ubuntu**, it does not happen on Windows 10 or other operating systems I've tried.

My problem is that every time I turn on my PC I need to unplug and reseat my USB network adapter. Otherwise the OS just acts like nothing is there. However when I reseat the adapter the operating system has no problem recognizing it and using it.

The network adapter is a Belkin N300 Wireless USB Adapter.

Comment: Pull down the network menu and select Connection Information. Note what driver is being used for your USB wireless adapter. Short answer... adding the driver to the file /etc/modules will load the driver at boot time, and the device should be known. Cheers, Al

Comment: Excellent! Thanks Al. You should post this as an answer so we can upvote it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed above... Pull down the network menu and select Connection Information. Note what driver is being used for your USB wireless adapter. Short answer... adding the driver to the file /etc/modules will load the driver at boot time, and the device should be known.

What was the driver name that you added?

Glad it worked for you!

Cheers, Al

Comment: Driver name was r8712u

Comment: Cannot upvote becauseI don't have 15 rep or something